# Graphs not plotting when in while loop menu

Tags: python, matplotlib

I have created a UI menu inside python by using a while true loop:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt


choice=input('enter a number')
while True:
    if choice == '1':
        pass
    elif choice == '2':
        pass
    elif choice == '3':
        plt.plot(range(100),range(100))
        plt.show()
```

running it outside the while loop plots the graph just fine, but inside the loop, empty figures show up instead, and then python crashes.

why is it that i can't plot it inside the while loop.

**Edit:**
I have been able to simplify the problem down to this:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

x,y=100
while True:
    plt.plot(x,y)
```

it seems the while True causes problems. any ideas?

Comment: See the example here. Hope it helps.

https://github.com/ASH-WICUS/Notebooks/blob/master/Separate%20and%20Distinct%20Charts%20from%20a%20Dataframe.ipynb

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try using the `plt.show()` in the loop

Comment: i tried it. No luck

Comment: @S12312 I think the graphs fill up your memory please try to show some finite number of plots before going for infinte.. try 10, 20 then check by increasing number

Comment: ok, it seems that once i added the plt.show() it runs in other IDEs, but not pycharm console. It could be something to do with the fact that i am using console and not the regular run.

Answer (score 1):

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt


choice=input('enter a number')
while True:
    if choice == '1':
        pass
    elif choice == '2':
        pass
    elif choice == '3':
        plt.plot(range(100),range(100))
        plt.show()
    choice=input('enter a number')
```